# Labeling 3D Surface Plots in MATLAB along respective axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have doubts regarding Labeling 3D Surface Plots in MATLAB along respective axes.

```
for j=1:length(op)
    x = op{j}(:,1);
    z = st:inc:en;
    y = op{j}(:,2:end);
    figure
    surf(x,z,y.','FaceAlpha',1.0) % surface plot
    xlabel('Non-Dimensional Number (k_0a)')
    ylabel('Non-Dimensional Horizontal Force (HF_P)')
    zlabel('Non-Dimensional Porous Parameter (G_S)')
    axis tight
    view(30,40)
    grid on
end
```

The result is the following 3D plot having labels not alligned in respective axis. Any help on alligning the labels in respective axes is highly appreciated.
Many Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the position and the rotation of the label as follow,

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
z = sin(x) + cos(y);
figure
surf(x,y,z,'FaceAlpha',1.0) % surface plot
xlabel('Non-Dimensional Number (k_0a)','FontSize', 20)
ylabel('Non-Dimensional Horizontal Force (HF_P)','FontSize', 20)
zlabel('Non-Dimensional Porous Parameter (G_S)','FontSize', 20)
axis tight
view(30,40)
grid on


xh = get(gca,'XLabel'); % Handle of the x label
set(xh, 'Units', 'Normalized')
pos = get(xh, 'Position');
set(xh, 'Position',pos.*[1,-0.5,1],'Rotation',-10)
yh = get(gca,'YLabel'); % Handle of the y label
set(yh, 'Units', 'Normalized')
pos = get(yh, 'Position');
set(yh, 'Position',pos.*[1,-0.7,1],'Rotation',30)
```

the results,

[image]

[Ref](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/168733-rotate-axes-labels-to-align-with-axes-angle-in-surfaces)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is helpful.